# Stop conversion of Longitude column to exponent while reading a file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a file in pandas where the longitude column is of the format like this- 10559E53 (105 degrees 59 minutes East 53 seconds).
When I print this data frame, python converts this to an exponent, something like 1.0559e+57. How can I stop this conversion?

Comment: How are you reading it, more exactly? read_csv?

Comment: Hi, yes , more specifically like this - data = pd.read_csv('28sept_navpoints',sep=';')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dtype` parameter to `read_csv` should be useful. Probably something like `dtype={'longitude': str}` (not tested).